# Display a simple path between two points using ngmap in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, direction, ng-map

I have followed the [Demo](https://ngmap.github.io/#/!directions2.html) and the github documentation of ngmap but still can't load a simple map with two points plotted and connected in it using the "directions" directive. (Weirdly though I can plot simple unconnected points in my map using the "marker" keyword)

I already included an apikey in my index.html file using the following format:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY"></script>
```

and added ngMap as a dependency in my modules.

and tested my codes in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/26Wa0aaDHrlDa2HWufY1?p=preview)

I'm sure I'm just missing out something very obvious in the tutorials. Appreciate all the help and thanks in advance.

EDIT:

template code snippet:

```
<ng-map zoom-to-include-markers="true" >
         <directions
          draggable="true"
          panel=""
          travel-mode=""
          origin="14.600631955983781,120.99075458943844"
          destination="14.600839603150039,120.98217152059078">
        </directions>
        </ng-map>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by adding a value to the waypoint property of directions.

```
<directions
          draggable="true"
          panel=""
          travel-mode=""
          waypoint = /* insert locations here in between origin and destination */
          origin="14.600631955983781,120.99075458943844"
          destination="14.600839603150039,120.98217152059078">
</directions>
```

Although I still haven't found a way for this to work in just routing two locations in a map.

Answer (score 0):

The way I used the waypoint for 2 location is as follow:

```
<directions
  draggable="true"
  panel=""
  travel-mode=""
  waypoint = {{ waypoints }}
  origin="14.600631955983781,120.99075458943844"
  destination="14.600839603150039,120.98217152059078">
</directions>

$scope.waypoints = [{
  location: 'lat,lon'
}, {
  location: 'lat,lon'
}]
```

For `waypoints`, the location key can either be `'lat,lon'` or an address in text. If its an address in text, google maps will infer the lat lon themselves